# Paint method repeats 3 times instead of 1

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to draw a rectangle when my input `arr[i][j]==1` but the paint method repeat the process 3 times. How can I fix it?

I called the paint from my main class like that:

```
new foo(cnv).start();//cnv is an Integer 2d array
```

And here is my foo class that draw the rectangles:

```
public class foo extends JPanel{
    Integer k[][];
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        int row=k.length;
        int col=k[0].length;
        System.out.println(row+" "+col);

        for(int i = 0; i < row; i+=1){
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j+=1){
                if (k[i][j]==1)
                    g.fillRect(i,j,10,10);        
            }        
        }    
    }

    public foo(Integer k[][]){
        this.k=k;
    }
    public void start(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new foo(k));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no problem, that's the way Swing works. A component is never painted just once. Components are repainted whenever Swing determines they should be repainted. For example if you resize a frame, the size of the components may change so the components are repainted. Also, custom painting should be done by overrinding paintComponent(…) not paint(…) and the first statement should be super.paintComponent(g) to make sure the background of the panel is cleared.

Comment: Thanks for comment but i do not understand how to solve it? I did not work with java swing or any graph library before so can you explain it on the code? @camickr

Comment: There is nothing to solve. The problem is NOT that the method is invoked multiple times. The problem is that your painting doesn't do what you expect. We don't know what you expect to the painting to do.

Comment: Actually I want to draw a rectangle instead of some digit for example in my k[][] array I have 0 and 1 when it is 1 I want to draw a rectangle that has size 10x10 and it started to draw from his original x,y position in the k array. Can you tell me how can i do that? @camickr

Comment: Basic math. The rectangle x/y values can't be the value of your index. You need to multiply the I/j values by 10, since the size of each square is 10.